# wcf service start

Tags: wcf, service

I have a wcf service inside a windows service. Inside the wcf service I have a http listener which needs to be started automatically when the windows service is started. Any ideas?

Comment: What's the problem with starting the listener in the Windows Service's `OnStart` method?
Have a look at Hosting and Consuming WCF services on MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx#msdnwcfhc_topic4

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I need to have the listener in the wcf service, because I'm going to interact with it a lot via messages from a desktop application. It works now, but only after I invoke a function of it. I want it to start automatically, not when I invoke any function.

Comment: hmm.... don't quite understand what you're trying to do really... if you have a WCF service, all you need to do is create the `ServiceHost` and call `.Open()` on it - that'll start up the WCF runtime (including the listeners)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the answers but I found the solution
In order to have your constructor called, you need this:

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single)]

Answer (score 0):

can you not use IIS to host the WCF service, it has the WAS (Windows Activation Service ) to start the WCF Service?